# Preventing AJAX calls to be cached in Google Closure Library

Tags: ajax, caching, google-closure-library

I can't find the way to turn off browser (and sometimes server "304") cache in GCL AJAX calls, like I've done in jQuery.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  cache: false,
});
```

Maybe I can control headers somehow?

I do not appreciate answers like adding a random string to a GET paramether *manually*. Like:

```
requestObject.send("/feed/get?id=" + id + '&nocache=' + new Date().getTime());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Cache` option in `$.ajax` puts [a timestamp in a GET parameter](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L677).

However, you could put `Cache-Control: no-cache` in the request headers when you are calling the [`send()`](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/class_goog_net_XhrIo.html#goog.net.XhrIo.prototype.send) method.

Comment: Could you please add some code sample? I really can't find how to add `cache-control`

Comment: Try: `goog.net.XhrIo.send(url, opt_callback, opt_method, opt_content, {'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'}, opt_timeoutInterval)`

Comment: Thanks for that code sample! (PS: how nice jQuery code looks compared to GCL)

Comment: This question would help a bit clarifying optional parameters: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356227/skipping-optional-function-parameters-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using xhrio to do the ajax, another way to do it is to set the header after you instantiate the xhrio.

```
var requestObject = new goog.net.XhrIo();
requestObject.headers.set('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
goog.events.listen(requestObject, goog.net.EventType.COMPLETE, function(e) {
    var obj = this.getResponseJson();
}); 
requestObject.send('http://example.com/jsoncontentsource');
```

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't work for me. Even when setting the headers, IE9 seems to cache the request. Only the QueryString seems to work :(