# jQuery .each() without index

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am wondering if there is a way to use the jQuery `$.each()` function **without** getting the index of the current element.

I am using the `$.each()` function verry often, but i always have to declare unused key variables like this:

```
$.each(data,function(unusedKey,subData){
    //Do something with subData
});
```

Is there another jQuery function which just returns the values?

**Note:**

I want to use a jQuery Function! I know that i could use a simple `for(var key in data)`, but I realy want to use jQuery!

**By the way:**

is the `$.each()` function noteable slower? Or can I use it at the most unnecessary points?

**Edit:**

By data i mean JSON-Data

Comment: You don't have to supply any function arguments whatsoever to `.each()`, just do `$('.example').each(function() { // blah blah });`

Comment: So, you're complaining about having to define the first argument to the callback just so you can use the 2nd argument.  That's a bit ridiculous.  The arguments are always there whether you declare a name for them or not (you can reach the one you want with `arguments[1]`) so it makes no difference if you make up a name for the first argument.  I see no reason why this question matters in any way.

Comment: jQuery's each is dumb and backwards compared to all the other now-standard array iteration methods. native is faster and has better arity (imho): [].forEach.call(data,function(subData){ });  or $(whatev).toArray().map(function(val,index){...}); the native methods also allow you to use _this_ instead of wasting it on repeating the current value, which makes iteration functions far more re-usable and generic.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356227/skipping-optional-function-parameters-in-javascript/8356945

Comment: @adeneo I asked specifically for the jQuery `$.each()` function...your duplicate link doesnt answer my question...by the way, i already got an answer...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just ignore the arguments altogether, and use `this`.

```
$('div').each(function () {
  $(this).hide();
});
```

or

```
$.each([1, 2, 3], function () {
  console.log(this * 2) 
});

// outputs 2, 4, 6
```

Comment: by data i meant json-Data :S sry i shoud mention this

Comment: Thanks! I didnt know i could use `this`!

Comment: There is no such thing as "json-Data". It's just data after it's decoded from JSON, and it's identical to an array/hash created by any other means.

Comment: I thought i could use `this` in combination with `$.each()` just if the data is an jQuery Element/Object :S

Comment: *"The $.each() function is not the same as $(selector).each(), which is used to iterate, exclusively, over a jQuery object."* [jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/). `$([]).each` work, but shouldn't be used for normal arrays...